# Histogram building in Python. Keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a variable for the probability of default for a set of loans `pd_vector` and I want to create a histogram for it but im new to python and don't understand the meaning behind the code i have below which I have taken off a lecturer of mine.

Was wondering if what im doing below is correct and why the errors are occuring

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd_vector = [213,23,324,435,54,657,768,879,78,23]
num_bins= 12
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(pd_vector, num_bins / alpha=0.7, n_width=0.05)
plt.grid
plt.show

  File "<ipython-input-11-eafbc0a73a47>", line 2
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(pd_vector, num_bins / alpha=0.7, n_width=0.05)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: The culprit is `num_bins / alpha=0.7`. Python thinks you're trying to pass a parameter `num_bins / alpha`, but that's an *expression*, not a *name*, so it's giving you an error. I *think* the issue is you need to replace `/` with `,` - does that work?

Comment: What is pd_vector here?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yes it helped thank you. There are loads of error messages with the final one being 'Unknown property n_width'. Any chance what that means and if theres a way i can make it more presentable

Comment: @jkazan its a list of 60 values for the probability of default for a set of loans

Comment: What module is `plt` again?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: Doing `help(pyplot.hist)` shows the parameters it can take. `n_width` is not one of them - did you mean `rwidth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of minor mistakes.

- As @Green Cloack Guy mentioned, n_width is not an option, you may mean rwidth.
- I believe you must call `grid` as `plt.grid(True)`
- I believe you must call `show` as `plt.show()`

Please note that, in your example code, it should be a working example, i.e. include `pd_vector` (you don't need all 60 elements, just some minimal working example), and the imports you make.

The following code is running, please try it and see if it does what you expect:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_bins= 12
pd_vector = [213,23,324,435,54,657,768,879,78,23]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(pd_vector, num_bins, alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.05)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

EDIT:

Per your request of a line following the histogram, you can try using the `numpy` and `scipty` packages like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

num_bins= 12
pd_vector = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, ))
density = stats.gaussian_kde(pd_vector)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(pd_vector, bins=np.linspace(-6, 6, num_bins), histtype=u'step', density=True)

plt.plot(bins, density(bins))
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Note that the bigger `num_bins`, the smoother the result.

Comment: thank you it works brilliantly. Is there a way I can add a line similar to a normal distribution curve on top of the histrogram, a line that follows the path of the histogram